# Why is at my Phonegap app only the padding-left applied with a min-width of 100%?

Tags: css, cordova

I am really quite a beginner with CSS and have some problems with it. For this problem I really tried to find an answer (and read several pages about margin, padding, box system,...) but I couldn't find a solution.

I am working on a Phonegap app and now I try to make the app a bit better looking. For that I want all the elements to be centred and the grey background should be at the whole page. To achieve that I put it all in a div class which has min-width and min-height set to 100%. Now I would want the elements to have a padding on the left and right side so that they are not completely sticking to the edges of the page. My problem is that only padding-left is applied (if I make the value bigger also the padding on the left side gets larger and moves the elements out of the screen when too large) but padding-right is completely ignored.

My HTML markup:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <title>Home Automatization</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="app">
        <h1>Relay switch</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h2> TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</h2>
        <br>
        <form>
        <label for="relay-switch">Relay:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-1" id="flip-checkbox-1" onchange="changeHandler()">
        </form>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button id="logout">Logout</button>
    </div>

</body>
```

The relevant CSS:

```
.app {
background-color:#E4E4E4; 
position:fixed;             
min-height:100%;
min-width:100%;
padding-top:60px;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
text-align:center;
```

Thank you very much in advance if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `padding` does not create a space outside of the element, for that use `margin`.

I think I've solved your issue using `calc(100% - 12px)` on your `width:`

https://jsfiddle.net/bb1yb9w2/

Comment: First: Thank you very much for your answer

The problem is that it doesn't 100% solve my issue. I have tried a similar approach like yours. The problem is just that I don't want any white border at the edges of my app. The bg-colour should be 100% of the page but the elements should be a bit inside. 

I am aware that padding doesn't create space outside the element. I want space between the edges of the element box and the elements inside.

Comment: @DesperateEi Sorry for not answering in 26 days lol. Here's a fiddle in which I think may be the answer: https://jsfiddle.net/bb1yb9w2/2/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll try it out when I have time. In the meanwhile I flipped to jQuery mobile for my project which basically offers what I need in a very simple way (without having to care too much about CSS).